# Xamarin ListView Grouping results in blackscreen

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app with Xamarin.Forms (xaml), but now i have a strange behavior with the grouping of the ListView

I have a ListView with a CustomCell if i display it without grouping everything works as expected, but if I set IsGroupingEnabled to true the screen is getting black.

Before Grouping:
[image: Without grouping]

With grouping
[image: With grouping]

I have no idea what i'm missing or what i did wrong.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cell="clr-namespace:BrindaApp.Cells"
             x:Class="BrindaApp.Tabs.MainTab" Title="Main">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Entry Placeholder="Search" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Entry>
            <Image x:Name="image_Group" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Group_Tapped"  />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductSource}" HasUnevenRows="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="mainListView"
                      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1,Constant=0}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="Black"
                          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Category}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Category}" IsGroupingEnabled="True">
                <ListView.Resources>

                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <cell:ProductCell ImageUrl="{Binding ProductImageUrl}" Difficult="{Binding Difficult}" Titel="{Binding Titel}" IsFavorit="{Binding IsFavorit}" ProductId="{Binding ProductId}"
                                          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=.2,Constant=0}" Height="200" Tapped="ProductCell_Tapped"
                                      ></cell:ProductCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            <!--</RelativeLayout>-->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <!--<Label Text="Some Text"/>-->
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainTab : ContentPage
    {
        ProductsViewModel viewModel;
        public bool IsGrouped { get; set; }
        public MainTab()
        {
            viewModel = new ProductsViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel.mainListView = mainListView;
            image_Group.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("BrindaApp.Imgs.group.png");


        }

        private void ProductCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetails());
        }

        private void Group_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(IsGrouped)
            {
                mainListView.IsGroupingEnabled = false;

            }
            else
            {
                mainListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
            }

            IsGrouped = !IsGrouped;
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class ProductModel
    {
        public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Titel { get; set; }
        public int Difficult { get; set; }
        public bool IsFavorit { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class ProductsViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        public ListView mainListView;
        ObservableCollection<ProductModel> productSource;
        public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> ProductSource
        {
            get
            {
                return productSource;
            }

            set
            {
                productSource = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("ProductSource");
            }


        }

        public ICommand RefreshListView { get; set; }

        public ProductsViewModel()
        {
            ProductSource = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
            ProductSource.Add(new ProductModel() { ProductImageUrl = "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/02/d7/5a/1c/essen-trinken.jpg", IsFavorit = true, Category = "Test" });
            ProductSource.Add(new ProductModel() { ProductImageUrl = "https://www.burgerking.at/003_at/website/slider/17_028_pop_cheesemas16_at/17_028_pop_cheesemas16_at_startseitenslider_01_product_angusclaus.png", Category = "Test" });
            ProductSource.Add(new ProductModel() { ProductImageUrl = "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/02/d7/5a/1c/essen-trinken.jpg", IsFavorit = true });
            ProductSource.Add(new ProductModel() { ProductImageUrl = "https://www.burgerking.at/003_at/website/slider/17_028_pop_cheesemas16_at/17_028_pop_cheesemas16_at_startseitenslider_01_product_angusclaus.png", Category = "Test" });
            FirePropertyChanged("ProductSource");


            RefreshListView = new Command(() =>
            {
                //TODO refresh list


                mainListView.IsRefreshing = false;
            },
             () =>
             {
                 return true;
             });
        }
    }
```

I'm struggeling here for days and cannot find an answer, hopefuly someone can help me.
As guid i used: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Grouping) you also referred to yourself, you are required to create a list of lists:

> Create a list of lists (a list of groups, each group being a list of elements).

Right now, you just have a flat list which is most likely why you experience your issue.

An example, also taken from the same link, is as follows:

```
static PageTypeGroup()
{
    List<PageTypeGroup> Groups = new List<PageTypeGroup> {
            new PageTypeGroup ("Alfa", "A"){
                new PageModel("Amelia", "Cedar", new switchCellPage(),""),
                new PageModel("Alfie", "Spruce", new switchCellPage(), "grapefruit.jpg"),
                new PageModel("Ava", "Pine", new switchCellPage(), "grapefruit.jpg"),
                new PageModel("Archie", "Maple", new switchCellPage(), "grapefruit.jpg")
            },
            new PageTypeGroup ("Bravo", "B"){
                new PageModel("Brooke", "Lumia", new switchCellPage(),""),
                new PageModel("Bobby", "Xperia", new switchCellPage(), "grapefruit.jpg"),
                new PageModel("Bella", "Desire", new switchCellPage(), "grapefruit.jpg"),
                new PageModel("Ben", "Chocolate", new switchCellPage(), "grapefruit.jpg")
            }
        }
        All = Groups; //set the publicly accessible list
}
```